# How to add net of divs by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I perform scrabble for web browser.

what I need to do is add net of divs for characters so the output effect should be like that :

```
 <div id="a1"></div> <div id="a2"></div>  <div id="a3"></div>  <div id=a4"></div>    <div id="a4"></div>  
 <div id="b1"></div>  <div id="b2"></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  
 <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  
 <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  
 <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>  <div></div>
```

I wonder how to implement something like that in jquery , I've tryied to to it by append method in loop :

```
( var i =  0 ; i < 15; i++)
    {
     $("#droppable").append("<div></div>")....
    }
```

but my dives have been replaced each other...

Changing css doesn't make result as well.

Can you help me ? What is the best way of creation net like that  ? Or maybe the best option is to make it simple , I mean manually :( ?

Comment: Can you give us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing what you've tried.

Comment: You could use a table instead of a bunch of divs.  That might make the formatting easier.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started:

<kbd>[**UPDATED x2 jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6r8N/2/)</kbd>

```
var aAlpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o'];
var aNum = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
var grid='';

for ( var i=0; i<15; i++) {
    grid += '<div class="hrow">';
    for (var j=0; j<15; j++) {
        grid += '<div class="grid" id="' +aAlpha[i]+aNum[j]+ '"></div>';
    }
    grid += '</div><br>';
}

$('#droppable').html(grid);
```